# How do I find out the keycodes for Ctrl+up and down arrow for TERM=screen?

Tags: terminal, osx, keyboard, tmux

I am using tmux a lot, and I have already managed to tune my OS X terminal to send the correct key codes for Ctrl+left and right arrow (`\033b` and `\033f`). I found those information on the web. However, I also need Ctrl+up and down to work correctly. How do I find out which key codes tmux expects? The `TERM` variable is set to `screen` while inside of tmux. Can I query the terminal database on my Linux machine for the codes?

At the moment, my OS X terminal simply sends arrow left and right, without the Ctrl modifier.

Comment: Try the methods I outlined in this U&L Q&A: [Key mappings in Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81166/key-mappings-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found that tmux seems to expect xterm keycodes, not minding the `screen` terminal type. Hence I just punched the keys in xterm, using Ctrl-V as a prefix and got these codes:

- left key: `^[[D`
- right key: `^[[C`
- up key: `^[[A`
- down key: `^[[B`
- C-left: `^[[1;5D`
- C-right: `^[[1;5C`
- C-up: `^[[1;5A`
- C-down: `^[[1;5B`

I can now configure OS X terminal to send those key codes, and tmux works fine. However, other apps running in tmux will break, because they don't expect to get xterm key codes. I found a workaround in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Setting_the_correct_term), which suggests to create your own terminfo entry. I will try that.

Edit: The tmux FAQ got me going, and I added the following two lines to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
setw -g xterm-keys on
```

Now I can use C-arrows in tmux, bash, emacs and other programs.

One more edit: Since tmux does not support bce (background color erasing), I needed to make my own terminfo, called xterm-256color-nobce:

```
infocmp xterm-256color | sed 's/bce, //' > xterm-256color-nobce
sudo tic ./xterm-256color-nobce
```

And made sure to use that as my default TERM value.

Comment: One more comment: I tried the ArchWiki approach, and it at least throws no errors. tmux now accepts C-arrow for resizing. However, bash, emacs and all other apps now report C-arrow as arrow. Terminal type is set to xterm-screen-256color, derived from screen-256color.

Comment: I have been looking more about the keycodes, and any light you can shed about why ^[[1;5A is Ctrl+Up, and so on would be very helpful. What is 1;5 in that? Another confusion I had was, if Ctrl is ^, and Alt is ^[, how does this system differentiate between Ctrl+[ key and Alt, and other such obvious problems?